# How to fix "TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'"?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe, typeerror

I'm trying to sample a dataframe using resample but whenever I try that, I get a TypeError. The error is in the last 2 lines of the code.

I'm still new to all this so I'm a bit confused about it. I keep getting "TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'"

```
import pandas as pd
import mailbox
import datetime
import pytz

MBOX = 'enron.mbox'
mbox = mailbox.mbox(MBOX)

mbox_dict = {}
for i, msg in enumerate(mbox):
    mbox_dict[i] = {}
    for header in msg.keys():
        mbox_dict[i][header] = msg[header]
    mbox_dict[i]['Body'] = msg.get_payload().replace('\n', ' ').replace('\t', ' ').replace('\r', ' ').strip()

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mbox_dict, orient='index')
df.index = df['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)

utc=pytz.UTC

start_date = '2002-1-1'
stop_date =  '2002-5-1'

date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
date_time_obj = utc.localize(date_time_obj)
start_time = date_time_obj.replace(tzinfo=utc)

date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(stop_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
date_time_obj = utc.localize(date_time_obj)
stop_time = date_time_obj.replace(tzinfo=utc)


datemask = ( df.index > start_time) & (df.index <= stop_time)


#*************here's when things go wrong *******************
vol_by_month = df.loc[datemask].resample('1M').count()['To']
print(vol_by_month)
```

Comment: Try changing line `df.index = df['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)` to `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` ?

Comment: didn't change anything :/